# unable to get the address of the element in the list by variant

Tags: c++, std-variant

I was trying to loop a list and getting the address of the element.
But all of the element's address is the same when using variant class.

```
int main()
{
    std::list<std::variant<std::list<int>, std::list<std::string>>> list_of_lists;
    std::list<int> int_list = {1, 2, 3};
    string a1 ="one";
    std::list<std::string> string_list = {a1, "two", "three"};

    list_of_lists.push_back(int_list);
    list_of_lists.push_back(string_list);

    // Iterate over all std::variant elements.
    for (const auto& v : list_of_lists) {
        // Check if the variant holds a list of ints.
        if (std::holds_alternative<std::list<int>>(v)) {
            // 'v' holds a list of ints.
            for (auto i : std::get<std::list<int>>(v)) {
                std::cout << i << ' ';
                cout<<&i<<endl;
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
            // Check if the variant holds a list of strings.
        else if (std::holds_alternative<std::list<std::string>>(v)) {
            // 'v' holds a list of strings.
            for (const auto& s : std::get<std::list<std::string>>(v)) {
                std::cout << s << ' ';
                cout<<"string: "<<&std::get<std::list<std::string>>(v)<<endl;
                cout<<&s<<endl;
            }
            std::cout << '\n';
        }
    }
    cout<<"a1 address: "<<&a1<<endl;
}
output:
1 0x8dfcac
2 0x8dfcac
3 0x8dfcac

one string: 0x8f2890
0x8f27d0
two string: 0x8f2890
0x8f2810
three string: 0x8f2890
0x8f2850

a1 address: 0x8dfcc0
```

As you ## Heading ##

It looks like the variant std library cannot get the original variable's own address. Thus, every time I try to loop through the linked list, all the address of elements in the mother list are changed. Thus, I can only display and I can not push back for those linked lists in the mother linked list. One of my friends told me c++ is all about pointer and he hates Java because it does have pointer! And now I can not use a pointer in c++ with this library. I have heard this problem can be solved by boot:: variant, std:: optional or polymorphism. But I have no idea how these work. Anyway, some people said the reason this library does not touch the address idea is because they have a disagreement about how what assignment

Comment: Can you post a [mre]?

Comment: Yes, I posted it.

Comment: You could remove `variant` from this code entirely and get the same behaviour.

Comment: so..I can not get the reference of the element? It looks like they are the same by type.

Answer (score 1):

For the `int` loop, you created a local variable and take its address.

```
for (auto i : std::get<std::list<int>>(v))  // local variable, same address each time
```

should be

```
for (auto& i : std::get<std::list<int>>(v)) // reference, refers to the actual element
```

This has nothing to do with variants.

For the `string` loop, you already use a reference.

```
for (const auto& s : std::get<std::list<std::string>>(v)) // reference
```

That's why things work as expected.

Comment: Nope, It is still wrong.  Even though I used & s, I am still unable to get the original address.

Comment: I can not see anything in the link you posted. It just keeps loading forever.

Comment: @ChannelNews I can. ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Wysf.png)) Maybe there is something wrong with your internet connection, but I am not sure.

Comment: I just checked. No, It does not work. Once they are in the loop, all elements' address are not the same. They are just different.

Comment: @ChannelNews If I understood it correctly, your question asks about why the addresses are the same.

Comment: My title is "unable to get the address of the element in the list by variant". Thus, my question is about the address of the element in the list by variant.

Comment: @ChannelNews A question begins with a word like "what" or "why" or is a yes/no question. Your question is a statement. A statement is not a question.

Comment: I think anyone can understand the title by what it means.